# Apache Camel and multithreading in a route. It doesn't wait for a "choice" route to finish

Tags: java, apache-camel

people. 
I have an (I hope) easy question for experts in Apache Camel. 
I have the following route (it's simplified to show where the error is, the route is working fine except for the error I'm explaining)

```
    from(ROUTE_URI)
        .routeId(ROUTE_ID)
        .choice()
            .when(simple(FILE_EXISTS))
                .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, INFO_MESSAGE_6)
                .to(PROCESS_1_ZIP)
                .to(PROCESS_2_ZIP)
                .process(ex -> ex.getIn().setBody(ex.getIn().getHeaders().get(HEADER)))
            .otherwise()
                .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, FILE_DOES_NOT_EXIST)
                .to(CHANGE_ZIP)
                .to(PROCESS_2_ZIP)
                .setHeader(HEADER, simple("true"))
        .end()

        .choice()
            .when(simple(OPTION_6))
                .process(this::translateToWhateverCommandWeWant)
                .to(ROUTE_URI)
                .process(ex -> ex.getIn().setBody(ex.getIn().getHeaders().get(HEADER)))
        .end()
        .to(UPDATE_FILE)
        .choice()
            .when(simple(OPTION_7))
                .to(CREATE_ZIP)
        .end()
        .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Finished process with ID blabla");
```

The route is working fine with this exception: I have checked some weird behaviour ( for me, I'm a newbie in Camel) which I don't understand. 
**UPDATE_FILE** is executed even when **FILE_EXISTS** option has not yet finished. So, sometimes the process fails because some files needed for that process to work are not available because they are created in step **FILE_EXISTS**.
Is this the normal behaviour for Camel?. 
I thought Camel waits for a choice path to finish before continuing the execution. 
I'm not using multiple threads or executing the step **FILE_EXISTS** in a different thread. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it possible that your route gets triggered multiple times and is run concurrently for that reason? An easy way to check is to add the thread name to the logging pattern and then add some debug log statements to your choice blocks.

Comment: Hey, @Ralf thanks for your help. I did it and even although that scenario is possible, it's not the case at all. I did the tests in local to check that behaviour, with only one attempt. There is no concurrency for my tests.

Comment: Then your `otherwise` block of the FILE_EXISTS check does not create all required resources for the UPDATE_FILE block to run through successfully?

Comment: The FILE_EXISTS stores some information in a DB and unzips the file. The step UPDATE_FILE uses those unzipped files to perform some operations. Did I answer your question?

Comment: Not quite. If the FILE_EXISTS condition evaluates to `false` you end up in the `otherwise`block. There you need to create all resources required for "FILE_UPDATE" to be able to run. Or you need to re-structure the route so FILE_UPDATE is executed only if FILE_EXISTS evaluates to `true`.

Comment: My bad. FILE_EXISTS evaluates always to true (test is set to do that). The issue is even when the choice path is not finished (zip is not finished of being unzipped) the FILE_UPDATE is triggered.

Comment: It depends on component, some components will not wait for task to finish by default. It would be helpful, if you can share variables used in `to` DSL.

Comment: It's not a "component" (if you are talking about some kind of camel component. Those are properties pointing to a JAVA bean in Spring configuration, a regular JAVA class to unzip a file.

Comment: I'd take a HARD look at the code doing the unzipping. It sounds like whatever you're using to do that isn't blocking waiting for the unzip to complete. Your expectation for how the steps in the pipeline would be processed makes sense, but it could be that the zip tool you're using is doing the work asynchronously or is hanging on to a file after returning.

Comment: Indeed, it is. We can mark this ticket as solved. A third party library which I can't change, was doing some operations asynchronously and that was the issue.  Thanks everyone for your help :)